# How to get menu reference from an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, junit

I am writing JUnit test scripts for an Android project. What I intent to test is the options menu items (you know, the menu invoked by pressing menu key) from an activity.

However, in our project the menu is generated dynamically from some internet content.
Most importantly, the Menu object is a private variable in our activity object.

Now my question is, how can I verify the this menu (verify its number of menuitems, text on each items, etc).

Answer (score 1):

To test the invocation of menu items you can use [Instrumentation.invokeMenuActionSync()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#invokeMenuActionSync%28android.app.Activity,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

The way you'd typically do this is make the members package private (no qualifier) in Java, then have your junit test live in the same Java package as the class that hosts the menu (probably your activity).

The unit test doesn't have to by physically co-located in the same same package folder, as long as both classes have the same package at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You would get reference to menu object using PhoneWindow. It has a private  static final class named "PanelFeatureState" , this class contains a field called   "MenuBuilder menu" , you would need reflection to access this class and its fields.
Menu inflator reads an xml resource file and stores the menu in this object.

To summarize :
PhoneWindow->PanelFeaturestate->MenuBuilder menu

You can get reference to PhoneWindow from activity using :
activity.getWindow()

Comment: Since PhoneWindow is not a public API , you would need to use Reflection. In my case I know the text of Menu Item but I needed to find ANdroidId of MenuItem so I am using reflection to get the Menu item and then read its androidId.